# How to return Vuex-generated page to client on initial Vue load?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

I have a Vue / Nuxtjs app which displays lots of user-provided content (think of it as a crowdsourced blog). The content on the client is retrieved and stored in Vuex. When a page is loaded, it displays the current content and then uses `fetch` to get the updated data. Here is a typical component:

```
  fetch() {
    this.$store.dispatch('feeds/refreshLatest')
  },
  computed: {
    feed() {
      return this.$store.state.feeds.latest
    }
  }
```

where `feeds/refreshLatest` uses `axios` to retrieve the posts.

This works quite well. The problem is the initial load is very slow, especially on the front page which has to process and display dozens of articles.

I have SSR enabled, and would like the server to store the content, and then on initial load provide a rendered page to the client. However, the Vuex object on the server seems to be new for each request, and so the client has to wait for the entire set of articles to be fetched before anything is displayed, which is unacceptable. Doing all the fetches only on the client solves this problem, but it is still too slow.

I thought I could somehow use the same server Vuex on each call and sending it to the client with `nuxtServerInit`, but I don't see a way to achieve sharing the Vuex. Thank you for any pointers or other packages which could help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is that after the fetch is finished after the api call in the server rendering, the DOM is dropped to the client, and the process is running every time and slow?

I solved similar issues using cookies. This is because cookies can also be used to render servers. I used the method below.

1. Store the data in the cookie after the initial api call, and send the data in the cookie to the client first.(If cookies are present, do not call api from server)
2. Call api from client to update data.

I use this library.

https://github.com/microcipcip/cookie-universal/tree/master/packages/cookie-universal-nuxt#readme

Comment: The problem is that the time to load the data on the server, as a response to the client call, is too long. The server does 10sec of downloading and parsing for every client request, so I just want to share that data across requests.